# Haskell: Monitor a file without polling (à la inotify in linux)

Tags: haskell, polling, inotify, busy-waiting

Is there a haskell library function to monitor a file without polling?

With polling i would do someting like this:

```
monitor file mtime handler = do
    threadDelay n -- sleep `n` ns
    t <- getModificationTime file
    if t > mtime
        then handler >> monitor file t handler
        else monitor file mtime handler
```

What I want is something like a blocking getModificationTime which will be woken up by the system. Is there something available?

I would be perfectly happy if it was available for posix systems only, but the more portable the better :-)

***Edit:*** I know [hinotify](http://code.haskell.org/hinotify/README.html), but I'm on a Mac (that's why I mention POSIX).

Comment: A wrapper around `hinotity` and `kqueue` depending on platform might be interesting.

Comment: Interesting question. Sorry to _me too_ this, is there anything on Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The kqueue package should do this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kqueue

Answer (score 7):

There was a GSoC project which resulted in the [fsnotify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fsnotify) package which uses system-specific libraries, and falls back to polling. It uses [hfsevents](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hfsevents) on Mac.

Comment: seems to be a nice library. I tried to build and install it (GHC 7.0.3, Mac OS X 10.6) but it did not work, due to a problem with hfsevents. So I'm going to stick with the above solution.

Comment: It would be great if you could file a bug report with the maintainer of hfsevents so he can fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The Package suggested by Sjoerd Visscher works like a charm (using GHC 7.0.3 and kqueue 0.1.2.4, Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard).

I compiled a quick sample using it (since I could not find API documentation, but there are some examples up on github):

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.KQueue.HighLevel (watchFile, EventType, Watcher)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

watch :: MVar EventType -> FilePath -> IO Watcher
watch chan file =
    let handler ev = putMVar chan ev
    in  watchFile file handler

listen :: MVar EventType -> IO ()
listen chan = takeMVar chan >>= print >> listen chan

main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        chan <- newEmptyMVar
        mapM (watch chan) args
        listen chan
```

This will create a little program which you can pass filepaths on as arguments and monitor these files. The Events are fed back through an `MVar` and read by the main thread which is basically a loop implemented by `listen`. The program has to be killed using `^C` since it is designed to run forever.